# What is the best Rails way to implement a continuous sidebar search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, search

I am trying to make a recipe website. I would love to have a sidebar where the user can add one ingredient at a time, where the main body would refresh and show only recipes that have that ingredient. I'm thinking AJAX will be great here.

BUT I'm not sure what the best Rails way to do these recursive searches would be. My ideas:

- Use session to save search terms---but I read somewhere that session is only meant to save short string data like ids.
- Create a new table resource to save search terms. Reset table with every new session.
- Duplicate recipes table and apply new search on current recipes only (those that passed previous search). Something like a table view, if I remember that right from when I took a db course.

I have implemented a simple search where I get search term from params and refresh the recipes appropriately. I need to keep narrowing those down with every new search, but just always start each search from `Recipe.all` at the moment.

I'm not sure what the best approach here is. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Like you said, use AJAX to query an API point. Have it return JSON. Using something like Angular or Knockout can make the view re-build even easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ajax**

You'll probably be looking for something called "[live search](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/14-jquery-live-search-plugins/)" or "autocomplete"

This works by taking an input (from your search box), sending it to an [endpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint) (as mentioned in the comments) (via ajax), and then displaying the results on screen

The "persistence" will be that you're keeping the data in the DOM, so you won't need to keep the data in the backend, unless you want to maintain the results throughout page transitions

> We've implemented something similar on [one of our dev sites](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk)

---

**Search**

You can either use [full text lookup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), or a third-party search like [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.io/)

The search can be handled like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
match 'search(/:search)', :to => 'recipes#search', :as => :search, via: [:get, :post]

#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
def search
    @recipes = Recipe.search(params[:search])
respond_to do |format|
    format.js   { render :partial => "elements/livesearch", :locals => {:search => @recipes, :query => params[:search]} }
    format.html { render :index }
    end
end
```

Uses [textacular gem](https://github.com/textacular/textacular):

```
#app/models/recipe.rb
def self.search(search)
    basic_search(name: search, description: search).take(5)
end

#app/views/elements/livesearch.html.erb
<%= search.each do |recipe| %>
    #your recipes
<% end %>
```

---

**JQuery**

The above code will return items from the database depending on your input text

You'll need to append it to the DOM, which is the realm of JQuery:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "#search_input", function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "/search"
       data: $(this).serialize();
       success: function(data) {
           //append to DOM
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You for giving me direction! This is an incredibly thorough answer. I appreciate this more than you think.

Comment: No probs - hopefully it will help you out!